# Error 1 'NUnit.Framework.TestCase' is not an attribute class

Tags: nunit, testcase

.....

```
    [NUnit.Framework.TestCase**("Chrome", TestName = "One")]
    [NUnit.Framework.TestCase(" Firefox", TestName = "Two")]
    [NUnit.Framework.TestCase("InternetExplorer", TestName = "Three")]
    public void TheRegisterTest(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/mercurywelcome.php");
```

.....

I am getting an error shown belowwhen i try to build the solution:

```
NUnit.Framework.TestCase' is not an attribute class
```

I'm using the following name spaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong class by specifying the full namespace.

Write your lines

```
[NUnit.Framework.TestCase(...
```

like this

```
[TestCase(...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error even when following Dio F's advice

```
[TestCase(...
```

It turns out I had an older version of NUnit installed. Installing version 2.6.2 fixed it though.